# Setting if else condition on Countdown Timer less than 10 second in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, countdowntimer

I am having some problem, how do i try set an if else condition if the timer is less than 10 second where it must alert user that they have 10 second remaining?

Here is the code for easier reference:

```
runTimer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d min: %02d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
                tvTime.setText(text);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {    
                runTimer.cancel();
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Check `if (millisUntilFinished < 10000){// Do something}`

Comment: as @Rotwang said, then show a dialog or notification or toast or whatever you want. And a pitfall: Add a boolean if you want to show the dialog once. And don't use `<= 10000` - sometimes you end up losing time between ticks, so you don't end up at exactly 10000 ms remaining

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! I know what to do already.

Comment: If any of you dont mind, is it alright to explain in terms of theory about Countdown Timer? I learn from a guy in YoutTube in doing a Simple Countdown Timer. But i want to know more about the theory behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code:

```
runTimer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        String text;
        if (millisUntilFinished < 1000)
            text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d min: %02d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
        tvTime.setText(text);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        runTimer.cancel();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
runTimer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (millisUntilFinished / 1000 == 10){

                 // SHOW MESSAGE HERE

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {    
            runTimer.cancel();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: `if (millisUntilFinished / 1000 == 10)` is less performant than `if (millisUntilFinished < 10000)` because you do a division (which is *expensive* - I prefer to *multiply by the inverse*) and a comparison instead of a single comparison.